# Python: Develope Multiple Linear Regression Model From Scrath

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to create a multiple linear regression model from scratch in python. Dataset used: `Boston Housing Dataset` from `Sklearn`. Since my focus was on the model building I did not perform any pre-processing steps on the data. However, I used an OLS model to calculate p-values and dropped 3 features from the data. After that, I used a Linear Regression model to find out the weights for each feature.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X=load_boston()
data=pd.DataFrame(X.data,columns=X.feature_names)
y=X.target
data.head()

#dropping three features
data=data.drop(['INDUS','NOX','AGE'],axis=1)

#new shape of the data (506,10) not including the target variable

#Passed the whole dataset to Linear Regression Model
model_lr=LinearRegression()
model_lr.fit(data,y)

model_lr.score(data,y)
0.7278959820021539

model_lr.intercept_
22.60536462807957   #----- intercept value

model_lr.coef_
array([-0.09649731,  0.05281081,  2.3802989 ,  3.94059598, -1.05476566,
        0.28259531, -0.01572265, -0.75651996,  0.01023922, -0.57069861]) #--- coefficients
```

Now I wanted to calculate the coefficients manually in excel before creating the model in python. To calculate the weights of each feature I used this formula:

[Calculating the Weights of the Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cErvY.jpg)

To calculate the intercept I used the formula
b0 = mean(y)-b1*mean(x1)-b2*(mean(x2)....-bn*mean(xn)

The intercept value from my calculations was 22.63551387(almost same to that of the model)

The problem is that the weights of the features from my calculation are far off from that of the sklearn linear model.

```
-0.002528644 #-- CRIM
-0.001028914 #-- Zn
-0.038663314 #-- CHAS
-0.035026972 #-- RM
-0.014275311 #-- DIS
-0.004058291 #-- RAD
-0.000241103 #-- TAX
-0.015035534 #-- PTRATIO
-0.000318376 #-- B
-0.006411897 #-- LSTAT
```

Using the first row as a test data to check my calculations, I get 22.73167044199992 while the Linear Regression model predicts 30.42657776. The original value is 24.

But as soon as I check for other rows the sklearn model is having more variation while the predictions made by the weights from my calculations are all showing values close to 22.

I think I am making a mistake in calculating the weights, but I am not sure where the problem is? Is there a mistake in my calculation? Why are all my coefficients from the calculations so close to 0?

Here is my Code for Calculating the coefficients:(beginner here)

```
 x_1=[]
 x_2=[]
 for i,j in zip(data['CRIM'],y):
      mean_x=data['CRIM'].mean()
      mean_y=np.mean(y)
      c=i-mean_x*(j-mean_y)
      d=(i-mean_x)**2
      x_1.append(c)
      x_2.append(d)
 print(sum(x_1)/sum(x_2))
```

Thank you for reading this long post, I appreciate it.

Comment: We need to see how you computed the coefficients (the code)

Comment: I think scikit-learn introduces additional bias in a different way if the `fit_intercept=True`. You can read the code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L375)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the trouble lies in the coefficient calculation. The formula you have given for calculating the coefficients is in scalar form, used for the simplest case of linear regression, namely with only one feature x.

[image]

EDIT

Now after seeing your code for the coefficient calculation, the problem is clearer. 
You cannot use this equation to calculate the coefficients of each feature independent of each other, as each coefficient will depend on all the features. I suggest you take a look at the derivation of the solution to this least squares optimization problem in the simple case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) and in the general case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). And as a general tip stick with matrix implementation whenever you can, as this is radically more efficient.

However, in this case we have a 10-dimensional feature vector, and so in matrix notation it becomes. 
[image]

See derivation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)

I suspect you made some computational error here, as implementing this in python using the scalar formula is more tedious and untidy than the matrix equivalent. But since you haven't shared this peace of your code its hard to know.

Here's an example of how you would implement it:

```
def calc_coefficients(X,Y):
    X=np.mat(X)
    Y = np.mat(Y)
    return np.dot((np.dot(np.transpose(X),X))**(-1),np.transpose(np.dot(Y,X)))

def score_r2(y_pred,y_true):
    ss_tot=np.power(y_true-y_true.mean(),2).sum()
    ss_res = np.power(y_true -y_pred,2).sum()
    return 1 -ss_res/ss_tot


X = np.ones(shape=(506,11))
X[:,1:] = data.values

B=calc_coefficients(X,y)
##### Coeffcients 
B[:]
matrix([[ 2.26053646e+01],
        [-9.64973063e-02],
        [ 5.28108077e-02],
        [ 2.38029890e+00],
        [ 3.94059598e+00],
        [-1.05476566e+00],
        [ 2.82595310e-01],
        [-1.57226536e-02],
        [-7.56519964e-01],
        [ 1.02392192e-02],
        [-5.70698610e-01]])

#### Intercept 
B[0]
matrix([[22.60536463]])

y_pred = np.dot(np.transpose(B),np.transpose(X))
##### First 5 rows predicted
np.array(y_pred)[0][:5]

array([30.42657776, 24.80818347, 30.69339701, 29.35761397, 28.6004966 ])

##### First 5 rows Ground Truth
y[:5]

array([24. , 21.6, 34.7, 33.4, 36.2])

### R^2 score
score_r2(y_pred,y)

0.7278959820021539
```

Comment: I have added my code on how I tried to calculate the coefficient to my question. I have updated it using your given formula but the answer is still far off from actual. Should i just stick to matrix notations for calculating coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Solution - 2020 - boston dataset**

As the other said, to compute the coefficients for the linear regression you have to compute

`β = (X^T X)^-1 X^T y`

This give you the coefficients ( all B for the feature + the intercept ).

**Be sure to add a column with all 1ones to the X for compute the intercept(more in the code)**

**Main.py**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np

from CustomLibrary import CustomLinearRegression
from CustomLibrary import CustomMeanSquaredError

boston = load_boston()
X = np.array(boston.data, dtype="f")
Y = np.array(boston.target, dtype="f")

regression = CustomLinearRegression()
regression.fit(X, Y)
print("Projection matrix sk:", regression.coefficients, "\n")
print("bias sk:", regression.intercept, "\n")

Y_pred = regression.predict(X)
loss_sk = CustomMeanSquaredError(Y, Y_pred)
print("Model performance:")
print("--------------------------------------")
print("MSE is {}".format(loss_sk))
print("\n")
```

**CustomLibrary.py**

```
import numpy as np

class CustomLinearRegression():
    def __init__(self):
        self.coefficients = None
        self.intercept = None

    def fit(self, x , y):
        x = self.add_one_column(x)

        x_T = np.transpose(x)
        inverse = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(x_T, x))
        pseudo_inverse = inverse.dot(x_T)
        coef = pseudo_inverse.dot(y)

        self.intercept = coef[0]
        self.coefficients = coef[1:]

        return coef

    def add_one_column(self, x):
        '''
        the fit method with x feature return x coefficients ( include the intercept)
        so for have the intercept + x feature coefficients we have to add one column ( in the beginning )
        with all 1ones
        '''

        X = np.ones(shape=(x.shape[0], x.shape[1] +1))
        X[:, 1:] = x
        return X


    def predict(self, x):
        predicted = np.array([])
        for sample in x:
            result = self.intercept
            for idx, feature_value_in_sample in enumerate(sample):
                result += feature_value_in_sample * self.coefficients[idx]
            predicted = np.append(predicted, result)

        return predicted


def CustomMeanSquaredError(Y, Y_pred):
    mse = 0
    for idx,data in enumerate(Y):
        mse += (data - Y_pred[idx])**2

    return  mse * (1 / len(Y))
```